# Hide Gradle pre-compiled plugins generated sources in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a gradle pre-compiled script plugin inside the `build-logic` project, which I use as an included build on `android-project`. The `Android` project tree view displays also the generated sources for `some-plugin` which I want to hide.

[image]

With this default setup, AS can resolve a reference for the extension `detekt` because is a generated accessor.

I can hide the generated sources by applying the `idea` plugin to `some-plugin` and excluding the `generated-sources` directory as follows:

```
// build-logic/settings.gradle.kts
gradle.beforeProject {
    pluginManager.apply("idea")

    configure<org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel> {
        module {
            // Exclude generated sources from AS project tree
            excludeDirs = setOf(
                file("${buildDir}/generated-sources/kotlin-dsl-plugins/kotlin"),
                file("${buildDir}/generated-sources/kotlin-dsl-accessors/kotlin"),
                file("${buildDir}/generated-sources/kotlin-dsl-external-plugin-spec-builders/kotlin")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Which effectively now take away the generated sources from the `Android` view:

[image]

But as you can see, the `detekt` extension is not longer resolved by AS. Build compiles successfully.

How can I hide the `generated-sources` files but still allowing AS to resolve references to the hidden files?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom [files scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#creating-a-new-custom-scope) and even [associate with a color](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#associate-file-color-with-a-scope) where you can exclude the needed directories and [set it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#views) for the Project tool window.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey but I want to keep the Android view and rather than switching to another scope I want to exclude the files from the Android view itself.